# C reference to structure member without initializing value

Tags: c, struct, initialization

Say there's a struct

```
   struct  refresh {
        int     endflag;
   };
```

and if I refer to `refresh.endflag` in a function yet I haven't given a value for the `endflag`, does it get initialized as 0? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you define the variable?

Comment: I just use the refresh.endflag value to compare to something in the main function. But I haven't assigned a value to refresh.endflag at all. So if I make a reference without initializing a value of an int struct member, does it automatically become 0 or does it give me error?

Comment: It depends on where you defined the variable.  Please update your question with a [mcve].

Comment: By variable, do you mean the structure member?

Comment: The member doesn't exist by itself.  It lives in an instance of the struct, for example `struct refresh refresh;`.  What you have above only defines the members of the struct, not an instance of it.

Comment: The instance of the structure is passed in as an argument of the function: struct refresh *refresh.

Comment: The structure that is passed in as an argument comes from another function, where it is defined like this: struct  refresh refresh;

Comment: Then the field values are undefined (has a value but cannot be predicted what the exact value is). Read the link for more details.

Comment: @SangjoonLee, If variable define inside a function and uninitialized, its value not predictable. It can be initialize with zero or not. leaving this variable uninitialized is undefined behavior.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot!

Comment: see this link: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/memory-layout-of-c-program/

Comment: gcc compiler produce warning with -Wall flag when try to leave local variables uninitialized: `untitled.c:98:2: warning: ‘insideFunction.endflag’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]     printf("inside function: %d\n", insideFunction.endflag);`

Comment: After all of that its better to be precise and initialize all variables you define.